# What is an index position of an uncle?

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, nodejs

I see [this document.](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v2.0.0-alpha.1/web3-eth.html#getuncle)
But I don't understand what is an index position of an uncle.

I'd like to get informations of uncle blocks like [etherscan.io](https://etherscan.io/uncles)

However I don't know a value of the index position what should be set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a block multiple uncles can be included. This method returns only one uncle.

```
web3.eth.getUncle(blockHashOrBlockNumber, uncleIndex [, callback])
```

`uncleIndex` is a number starting from `0` which represents which uncle will be returned.

If for example a block has 2 uncles, the first uncle has `uncleIndex=0` while the second uncle has `uncleIndex=1`.